# Formatting of a \longtable containing a picture

Tags: tables, graphics

I have a large table (spanning several pages) where also images are inserted (example is only part of the table). I've been looking for a solution how to vertically adjust the position of the images in the table but so far without success. Now the text is aligned with the bottom of the figure and that's not pretty. Would someone have a suggestion how to get the figures drop down by half their height in the column so that the text in the adjacent columns would be in the middle of the figure?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,inner=2cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\centering 
\captionof{table}{Properties of the selected pharmaceuticals}
\label{tab:Properties}
\begin{longtable}{ccccccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Therapeutic class} & \textbf{Pharmaceutical} &      \textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{Molecular structure} & \textbf{Log Kow} & \textbf{Kd (L/kgSS)} & \textbf{Reference} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Beta-blockers} & Atenolol & ATL &\includegraphics{figures/ATL.png}& 0.16 &\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}64\\38\\1-8\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}1\\2\\3\end{tabular}\\
    &Bisoprolol&BSP&\includegraphics{figures/ATL.png}&1.87&n.a.&\\
    &Metoprolol&MTP&\includegraphics[height=0.8in]{figures/ATL.png}&1.88&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}1\\10-90\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}2\\3\end{tabular}\\
    &Sotalol&STL&\includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/ATL.png}&0.24&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}37\\10-60\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}2\\3\end{tabular}\\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Analgesic}&Diclofenac&DCF&\includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/ATL.png}&4.51&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}118\\1.58\\16\\151\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}1\\4\\5\\6\end{tabular}\\
    &Tramadol&TMD&\includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/ATL.png}&3.01&47&7\\
    \midrule
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atenolol#/media/File:Atenolol.svg

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Please can you add again your picture?

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution: use a m-column, as this aligns the cell contents vertically in the middle.

I added a newcolumntype "C", which takes the width of the column, you'll have to define.  I replaced your 3rd "c"-column by my new "C"-column, making it 7.5cm wide.

You should also insert the images with `\includegraphics[width=linewidth]{filename}` commands.  Please notice: a) I scaled the image with `width=\linewidth` as `\linewidth` automatically reflects the actual width of your column.  If you change my (guessed) 7.5cm to 5 cm, `\linewidth` will be decreased accordingly.  b) You do not need to add the file name extension ".jpg".  PDFLaTeX will search for the existance of ".jpg" ".png" and ".pdf" for itself.  (And if you happen to use classical LaTeX, it will search for ".ps", ".eps", ".ps.gz" and finally ".eps.gz".)

Here is the (no so minimal) example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,inner=2cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}

%% New column, define the width as #1, the m-column will align all
%% content in ther vertical middle, \centering will align it in the
%% horizontal middle.
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
  >{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\begin{document}
\afterpage{
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\centering 
\captionof{table}{Properties of the selected pharmaceuticals}
\label{tab:Properties}
%\begin{longtable}{ccccccc}
\begin{longtable}{cccC{7.5cm}ccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Therapeutic class} & \textbf{Pharmaceutical} &      \textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{Molecular structure} & \textbf{Log Kow} & \textbf{Kd (L/kgSS)} & \textbf{Reference} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Beta-blockers} & Atenolol & ATL &\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/ATL.png}& 0.16 &\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}64\\38\\1-8\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}1\\2\\3\end{tabular}\\
    &Bisoprolol&BSP&\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/ATL.png}&1.87&n.a.&\\
    &Metoprolol&MTP&\includegraphics[height=0.8in]{figures/ATL.png}&1.88&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}1\\10-90\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}2\\3\end{tabular}\\
    &Sotalol&STL&\includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/ATL.png}&0.24&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}37\\10-60\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}2\\3\end{tabular}\\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Analgesic}&Diclofenac&DCF&\includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/ATL.png}&4.51&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}118\\1.58\\16\\151\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}1\\4\\5\\6\end{tabular}\\
    &Tramadol&TMD&\includegraphics[height=1in]{figures/ATL.png}&3.01&47&7\\
    \midrule
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

And this is a cutout of the result.

[image]

Comment: I am pleased, that it helped you.  Have a fine day.

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{makecell}
...
\makecell[c]{\includegraphics{figures/ATL.png}}
```

Comment: The `[c]` (more exactly `[cc]`) optional argument  is the default.

Comment: Yes, it is if you don't redefine `\cellalign`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics{...}}` usually does the trick.